# DBMS scheduler error ORA-27465: invalid value freq=weekly;?byday=sun; byhour=22; byminute=0;

Tags: oracle

```
    begin
Dbms_Scheduler.Create_Job(
job_name => 'JOB_HK_SALES'
,job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
,job_action => 'BEGIN leadcapture.delete_old_records_SND(); END;'
,start_date => '30-SEP-2016 22:00:00'
,repeat_interval => 'freq=WEEKLY; byday=sun; byhour=22; byminute=0; bysecond=0;'
,enabled => TRUE
,Comments => 'Job to housekeep table records.');
end;
/
```

I am getting below error after running above procedure

```
ORA-27465: invalid value freq=weekly;?byday=sun; byhour=22; byminute=0; bysecond=0; for attribute REPEAT_INTERVAL
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 99
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 262
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Kindly suggest!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's possible you have an invalid character just before "byday", remove the spaces between the parameters and try it again. on first glance it does look ok

Comment: Thanks , I removed spaces and its working.

Comment: On my instance it was compiled w/o problem. Check non printable characters or copy+paste statement and run it again.

Comment: You can also try `freq=DAILY;`. Since you specified `byday=sun;` it will run only on Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is syntactically ok. You can simply check your script for undesirable characters before you try to compile it. Use something like this:

```
grep -aq -e '[^[:print:]]' create_job.sql
```